# Titanium editing textField in a listView

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have a listView that has a textField in the item template. To make sure that the listView saves the data I have used the code from this [link](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/152482/getting-the-value-of-a-textfield-in-listview) it works in that it saves the data to the listView item but it looses focus every time the onChange event fires the updateItemAt method so the keyboard disappears after every key press.

I have tried onBlur but I then get the original text flashing up before it is replaced with the new text from the blur event.

Is there a way to stop loosing focus when the updateItemAt listView method is fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not, because by `updateItemAt` you are re-rendering that row.

Also, its not a best practice to store data in proxy objects. Better store the data in the data collection that drives your listview or a separate object/array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, does this mean that I cannot use a text field directly in a row item of a list view?

Comment: You can, but just save the data elsewhere as I suggested, and not in the row.

Comment: If I don't update the row, when I scroll up and down the value will visually disappear even if I save it to the data source. Sorry for all the comments

Comment: Ah... that's an interesting one. I can understand why that is happening. ListViews renders only the rows in sight. I guess the onblur is then the only option, or to use TableView.

Comment: Saving the data outside of the proxy object worked, so that I save data on change and update the view on blur. Thanks

Comment: Hi @pete80, how did you solve the problem where the keyboard starts to hide the minute you register a blur event on the text field? Switching between the text fields is now not a great experience.